# When would I want to use the Add method, and not the Attach method?

Tags: entity-framework-core

I know there are existing/older questions on difference between `Add` and `Attach` methods of the `DbSet<TEntity>` class. To be clear, I'm not asking that question again. I know how they work and the functional difference between them.

What I understand from what they do behind the scene (as described in their documentations) is, `Attach` completely covers `Add`'s functionality (please correct me if I'm wrong). Better yet, it does that in a more careful way (in disconnected graph, marks an entity as `Unchanged` instead of `Added` if it has the PK value set).

That's what makes me wonder about the reason behind the existence of the `Add` method. I mostly use EF Core with disconnected entities, and there might be scenarios that I'm not aware of.

So, what could be a possible scenario where I might want to use the `Add` method because the `Attach` method wouldn't be appropriate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two reasons:

1. To make code self-explanatory. If you create a new entity object, `Add` it, don't `Attach` it. Not all developers will understand that attaching an entity may mark it as `Added`.
2. To enforce that an entity is marked for insert. For example when "cloning" an existing entity (i.e. save it as a new database record). EF will mark the existing entity as `Added` irrespective of its key value(s) and insert it as a new row in the database.

As for the second point, when the primary key is auto-generated, in EF6 that's all there was to it, EF will insert the entity and get its new key value(s) from the database. EF core will try to insert the new entity with existing key values, so you first have to clear them, i.e. set them to their default values.

In short: use `Add` for code that is designed to add data, `Attach` when attaching objects that may be any mix of new or existing entities.

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit the cloning scenario, and Add method's role in the process? Didn't really get that.

Comment: "EF core will try to insert the new entity with existing key values..." - are talking about `Add` or `Attach` here? AFAIK in both case (Add or Attach) EF will throw exception telling you that another instance with same key is already being tracked, if I fetch it from db before cloning.

Comment: No, it's still the same instance. Only its state is changed by adding it (so yes, it's about `Add`).

Comment: OK, may be I misunderstood. By "cloning" you didn't meant using 'MemberwiseClone', just fetch the existing entity, and `Add` it, right? But even so, `Add` will fail by throwing exception when `SaveChanges` is called and `Attach` wouldn't generate any change - how does that makes me prefer `Add` over `Attach`?

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. Modified it. As for the exception, all I can say is: I can get an entity from the database, mark it as added (after clearing its key) and save it successfully.

Comment: Yes, that certainly is a scenario specific to `Add`, where `Attach` complains that the key cannot be modified. Thanks for clarifying.